# Conjugacy Class of symmetry group $S_{10}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $X=\{a\in S_{10} | ~~\text{order}(a)=8\}$. Determine how many conjugacy classes are in $X$.

How to do this question in general?

Comment: Do you mean for arbitrary orders in arbitrary symmetric groups? Do you see how to do it in this case?

Comment: No in this case. But the other question I'm trying to do is slightly different.

Comment: In that case: Do you know what the conjugacy classes look like in the symmetric groups? Do you know what an element of order $8$ looks like?

Comment: I know it for S4 or something. There are too many for S10 or like S20. I'm guessing there a way to do it without listing it all out?

Comment: @fjiao03: Do u know about GAP?

Comment: @Babak: GAP would tell you the answer to this question, but I think he wants to learn how the answer is calculated.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes. In fact, I wanted the OP to examine the problem by GAP just to find and construct a theoretical idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint #2: It suffices to consider disjoint cycle decompositions for which every cycle is of length 2,4 or 8.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider [cycle decompositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_decomposition_(group_theory)).